# session lost randomly after removing index.php from URL's

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla3.0

I have ecommerce application on joomshopping(i.e An ecommerce extension for joomla), and I have removed index.php from URL's. Now, cart session is destroying automatically and randomly at any step.
For removing index.php, I have **enabled Search Engine Friendly URL's and URL rewriting** from joomla admin. I am using ubuntu14.04 and placed .htaccess file on root directory.
My application is put in sub directory names as http://www.example.com/demoinstance . 
I have done following changes for SEF URL's:-
1) .htaccess code

```
##
# @package    Joomla
# @copyright  Copyright (C) 2005 - 2014 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license    GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
#Options +FollowSymLinks
## Mod_rewrite in use.

<FilesMatch "\\.(html|htm|php|js)$">
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
</FilesMatch>

RewriteEngine On

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com/demoinstance [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/demoinstance/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage

RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
## Begin - Custom redirects
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
## End - Custom redirects
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).

RewriteBase /demoinstance/
## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
##End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

2) in /etc/apache2/sites-available/000.default.conf :-

```
<Directory '/var/www/html'>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

3) Gzip is not enabled.

4) In phpinfo:-

```
session.save_path   /var/www/html/example/session   /var/www/html/demoinstance/session
```

5) Fiddler responses:- there is no 404/302 errors. 303/403/202 response are coming.

Please help me out. I am facing this issue from past 20 days and yet not found any solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just a tip, session is generated and maintained by your php application, you won't find anything useful about it looking at the apache configuration. Another tip, you can remove your last 4 rewrite directives with a single `FallbackResource /index.php` line

Comment: This issue is coming after removing index.php from URL's, otherwise sessions are working perfectly with index.php. Please help :(

Comment: At least try FallBackResource as I mentioned. index.php won't be in urls, but it will load, as for a default load page DirectoryIndex index.php  should be used too. Try both, remove your 4 last rewriterules, and share your findings.

Comment: I have removed 

`   RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
`
and added 

   `FallbackResource /index.php`

result was 404 not found.

Comment: again session was cleared after using `FallbackResource /index.php` in .htaccess

Comment: What I'm trying to tell you is, even so, session is not something handled or even touched in your actual Apache configuration. Review and debug your application.

Comment: Just a "dumb" question, did you try reboot your OS? Cause I had a similar problem and it has been solved just rebooting the OS (Debian Jessie).